# Results not showing in the ListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I've been working on an android app ... I am stuck at a point ... after getting the JSON data from the internet I am having trouble to show it in the `ListView` ... Below is my code ...

```
public class MainListActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    protected String[] mBlogPostTitles;
    protected JSONObject mBlogData;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainListActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> titleAdapter;



    public MainListActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            GetBlogPost getBlogPost = new GetBlogPost();
            getBlogPost.execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        List<String> blogTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mBlogPostTitles));
        titleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.name_lst_view,
                R.id.name_list_view_textview,
                blogTitles
        );

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);
        listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter);

        return rootView;

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }


    private void updateList() {
        if(mBlogData == null){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Oopps");
            builder.setMessage("There was an error accessing the blog ...");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();


        }else {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");

                mBlogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = post.getString("title");
                    title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                    mBlogPostTitles[i] = title;


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class GetBlogPost extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {
        public final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 5;

        int responseCode = -1;
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {


            try {
                URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=americancuisines&count="+NUMBER_OF_POSTS);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();

                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        return null;
                    }
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                        // buffer for debugging.
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                        return null;
                    }
                    String blogDataJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(blogDataJsonStr);

                }else {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IO Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mBlogData = result;
            updateList();

        }
    }

}
```

From the above code you can see that i am getting that data through `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` ... Data is coming through perfectly as I can see through the logcat ... The issue is somewhere in this method which I can't seem to figure out ..

```
private void updateList() {
    if(mBlogData == null){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Oopps");
        builder.setMessage("There was an error accessing the blog ...");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


    }else {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");

            mBlogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString("title");
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                mBlogPostTitles[i] = title;


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
        }
    }
}
```

The above method is called in `onPostExecute` I mean if i print to logcat within this method I can see the results being printed but when I try to show those results in the `onCreateView` method results don't show up not even in the logcat ... Any help will be appreciated ... Thanks

Comment: notifydatasetchanged in on  updateList() or after onPostExecute but where is your list adapter

Comment: where is listview in your code?

Comment: it was in the on create method .. I deleted it ... let me re post the code ...

Comment: updated the code ... please have a look at it ... Thanks

Comment: @Madhur ... where should i use the `notifydatasetchanged` ??

Comment: titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in updateList() after for loop

Comment: Ok ... Let me try and get back to you ...

Comment: In the `updateList()` method add the new elements to the `blogTitles` instead of creating a new array and call `titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` once that is done. In order to do that, you will have to define `blogTitles` as a class variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as following:

```
public class MainListActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    protected String[] mBlogPostTitles;
    protected JSONObject mBlogData;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainListActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> titleAdapter;
    ListView listView;


public MainListActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);


         if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        GetBlogPost getBlogPost = new GetBlogPost();
        getBlogPost.execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return rootView;

}

private void updateList() {
    if(mBlogData == null){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Oopps");
        builder.setMessage("There was an error accessing the blog ...");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


    }else {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");

            mBlogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString("title");
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                mBlogPostTitles[i] = title;


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
        }
    }
}

public class GetBlogPost extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {
    public final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 5;

    int responseCode = -1;
    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {
            URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=americancuisines&count="+NUMBER_OF_POSTS);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                String blogDataJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(blogDataJsonStr);

            }else {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IO Exception Caught: ",e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mBlogData = result;
        updateList();

        List<String> blogTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mBlogPostTitles));
        titleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.name_list_view,
                R.id.name_list_view_textview,
                blogTitles
        );
        listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have made some changes to my code and it work here is the latest code ... if you want to see ... slightly different from yours but same thing ... http://pastebin.com/WDdwbB7U

Answer (score 0):

Use same array list in both update and initialize so globally declare a single array list and update it in `updateList()` method,
Try like this,

```
     try {
                JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");

                mBlogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];//remove this and use the 
                                                    //same as you are using in adapter
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = post.getString("title");
                    title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                    mBlogPostTitles[i] = title;
                }
    titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//here

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
```

**OR** even you can use in `onPostExecute`

```
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                mBlogData = result;
                updateList();
                 titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//here
            }
```

Comment: Madhur tried your suggestion and my app crashed ... what do you mean by this  `mBlogPostTitles = new String[jsonPosts.length()];//remove this and use the 
                                                    //same as you are using in adapter`

Comment: i mean use the same arraylist which you are using in oncreateview so declare a global variable as List<String> blogTitles = new ArrayList<>; and use blogTitles every where

Comment: so I should define `blogTitles` as a class variable ?

Comment: My app is crashing ... is the code correct now please check http://pastebin.com/0UkJFjDu

Comment: y are you doing    titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter); in post execute  use listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter);  above return root view

Comment: I have pasted my code to pastebin the link is in my comment above ... Can you check and correct me ... Thanks

Comment: yes i have seen it thats y am asking y are you doing titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter); in post execute use listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter); above return root view

Comment: Ok I removed `listView.SetAdapter(titleAdapter);` from `onPostExecute` method and placed it above `return rootView` ... But when I run the app it crashes and in logcat it points me to line 67 `blogTitles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mBlogPostTitles));`

Comment: Madhur I tried the code you sent me on the paste bin ... but my app crashed after a while like after 10 - 15 secs ... here are are the logcat errors http://pastebin.com/qFRKRVMd

Comment: One more thing while the app was running for 10 - 15 secs ... the list of the titles never appeared ..

Comment: initialize mBlogPostTitles=new String[jsonPosts.length()] i got confused with too many array just add again this line in update

Comment: Madhur ... after initializing `mBlogPostTitles=new String[jsonPosts.length()]` in the `updatelist` method  the app didn't crashed ... but the titles are still not there ... what could be the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103820/discussion-between-madhur-and-faisalblink).

Answer (score 0):

find the listview : `ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);` before calling

```
GetBlogPost getBlogPost = new GetBlogPost();
getBlogPost.execute();
```

and put this line `listView.setAdapter(titleAdapter);` in your `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: can you tell what error you are seeing from the logcat?

Comment: whats in line 111 in MainListActivityFragment.java?

Comment: `mBlogPostTitles[i] = title;`

Comment: in your code, make this change

` titleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.name_lst_view,
                R.id.name_list_view_textview,
                blogTitles
        );`

Comment: my code is already like you have suggested ... if you want you can see my latest code here http://pastebin.com/WDdwbB7U

Comment: check this http://pastebin.com/RrAfjLtF . I have made few changes. you dont have to make changes to `doInBackground()`. change the rest and you are good to go.